# Using the Split() method in Java

Tags: java, string, parsing

I am trying to split an input like the following:

0-0-1-0;Wolf Blitzer;leaf

with the following code:

```
        public static void buildTree(String treeFile){
        //temp string array to hold the input as 3 seperate Strings, seperated by ;
        String[] temp= new String[3];
        int i=0;

        //will split the string into its 3 parts
        for (String newTemp: treeFile.split(";")) {
            temp[i]=newTemp;
            i++;
           }

        //can hold up to 100 char, each describing a path
        char[] pathArray= new char[100];
        int pathCursor=0;

        i=0;
        //once again split the first part of the string, which holds the path, into an array of chars,
        //parse each String into a char and then set equal to in array in array
        for(String newTemp: temp[0].split("-")){
            char c=newTemp.charAt(0);
            pathArray[i]=c;
            i++;
            pathCursor++;
        }

        for(int j=0; j<3;j++){
            System.out.println(temp[j]);
        }

        for(int j=0; j<pathCursor;j++){
            System.out.println(pathArray[j]);
        }
    }
```

When I encounter spaces such as the the space in Wolf Blitzer, or periods in titles such as Dr. Strange, my split function doesn't work correctly. I thought that it would only split at whatever character I defined (in this case the ; and later the -). Am I not understanding split() correctly?

EDIT:
My expected output should be:
0-0-1-0
Wolf Blitzer
Leaf
0
0
1
0

Also I am trying to diagnose the issue and therefore am manually passing in the TreeFile with a simple test file which just asks for a string and then calls the method

Comment: works fine for me `0-0-1-0
Wolf Blitzer
leaf
0
0
1
0
`

Comment: What is your desired output for `0-0-1-0;Wolf Blitzer;leaf`?

Comment: BTW `String temp[] = treeFile.split(";");`

Comment: 0-0-1-0   Wolf    null         is what I get

Comment: and input like:   0-0-0-1-0;tom;leaf   works fine for me

Comment: check the value of `treeFile`

Comment: Please edit your post to add expected output.

Comment: @ScaryWombat why are you setting the temp String array equal to the split? Doesn't split need to be inside a for loop so that the subsequent splits can be stored in next memory block

Comment: no it does not need to be in a loop. try it.

Comment: You guys were right and my inputting was being done incorrectly (even in my test class). I instantiated a scanner object and used .next(); which was causing my error. Changed to .nextLine() and it started to work. Thanks!